# Porting from platform.popen to subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a bunch of code that uses the old deprecated `popen` from the `platform` package.  Since this is deprecated, I will be moving this to the `subprocess` package.

What is the equivalent statement to `popen("some_command")`?  Is there a reason that popen was deprecated?

Comment: it's simple. Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: The documentation explains how it replaces os.popen, not platform.popen.  A regular statement is simply "platform.popen("python some_script.py")"

Comment: does it make *any* difference?

Comment: Why not just `import some_script`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  I get your point and almost said the same thing, but am assuming that is just an example and the command could be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `platform.popen` has not been deprecated as best as I can tell. However, this is a low-level function that you should not make use of for flexibility and portability reasons.
- Lots of other process-launching things were deprecated and some removed in Python 3. Many, many attempts at doing this well were made in the history of Python, and `subprocess.Popen` and its convenience functions are by far the best. After its existence the others became cruft and most of the retained ones are just there to support legacy code.
- If you're going to port your code to use the `subprocess` module, **don't look for an exact equivalent to what you have been doing, or you will miss out on the ways in which it is better**. Read and understand the `subprocess` documentation and understand the ideas it is using to solve the problem of process-launching better than the older alternatives.

  How is `subprocess.Popen` better than the older alternatives?

  - **It is secure.** Instead of `something('shell command here')`, we do `Popen(['shell', 'command', 'here'])`. This doesn't launch an unnecessary shell process, which makes it less errorprone and dangerous.

    Consider if I asked the user for their name to be input. I might write `something('foo %s" % name)` in the old thing. It should work--if the user gives you the name "Mike", then it becomes a command like `foo Mike`. But what if the user's name is "Mike Graham"? Then I want `foo 'Mike Graham'`. So now I always put in the apostrophes, but now what if the user's name is `"Mike O'Reilley"`? Worse yet, what if his name is `"Mike; rm -rf /"`? The solution here isn't to try to escape these yourself (which is hard to do right, let alone to do cross-platform), but to pass the arguments directly without bothering with the shell--`Popen(['foo'`, name])`.
  - **It is flexible.** You can control the input and output fully.
  - **It is nonblocking.** `Popen` can run a process concurrently with yours.